# Double Parse into an 2D array or jagged array

Tags: string, parsing, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I have a text file that consist of

```
name,definition;
name1,definition;
name2, definition;
```

i know how to split the the string that is being taken into the script from the text file but i dont know how to get it all into a 2darray or jagged array.

it should look like this after words

```
array[0][0] = name;
array[0][1] = definition;
```

SORRY, i forgot to say what language, its in C#

Comment: What language would this be in? Java? C#? Ruby?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention language c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your solution in JavaScript. **note** If your row values can contain quotes, new lines, or escaped delimiters more parsing is necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/N4YYA/

```
var result = [];
var txt = document.getElementById("test").value;
// get lines
var lines = txt.split(";");
for(var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    // get and trim whitespace off the line
    var line = lines[i].replace(/(^[\s\r\n]*|[\s\r\n]*$)/g, "");
    var values = line.split(",");
    var row = [];
    for(var j=0; j<values.length; j++) {
        // get and trim whitespace off each value
        var value = values[j].replace(/(^[\s\r\n]*|[\s\r\n]*$)/g, "");
        // add it to your row array
        row.push(value);
    }
    // add row to results
    result.push(row);
}

// debug show result
var o = document.getElementById("outp");
for(var x=0; x<result.length; x++)
    o.innerHTML += result[x].toString() + "<br/>";
```

Comment: this is basically what i was looking for just in C# which i forgot to mention above, sorry for forgetting to say it

Comment: @imGreg - OK then take this JavaScript code and replace all "result = []" with "result = new List<List<string>>()" and "row = []" with "row = new List<string>()" and ".push" with ".Add" and ".replace(...)" with ".trim()" also, make sure to capitalize the S in .Split. That should do it.

Comment: im getting an error at the trim lines.  Im using Unity3D with C# and its saying unexpected symbols to all the characters in the trim function

Comment: `var line = lines[i].trim(([\r\n]*|[\r\n]*$)/g, "");
var value = values[j].trim((^[\r\n]*|[\s\r\n]*$)/g, "");`

Comment: @imGreg - You can't use literal Regex expressions in C# also the c# .Trim() function with a capital T (like all object functions in C#) does not take any parameters.

Comment: weird in the IDE im using it only allows me to call Trim on the array not objects in the array

Comment: @imGreg - You should be able to call Trim on Strings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In C#:

```
string[][] array = inputString.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToArray();
```

and if you want to include the trim for some reason:

```
string[][] array = inputString.Split(';').Select(x => x.Split(',').Select(y=>y.Trim()).ToArray()).ToArray();
```